# How To Create a PDF file in raw in Android

Tags: android, pdf

How to Create A PDF fiel in raw ..Eventhough I Was using iText.jar I was geting an error specifying File Not Found Error and also saying File cannot be Opened .Here is the code

/** Called when the activity is first created. */

```
EditText editText;
Button button;
private static String FILE = "C:/FirstPdf.pdf";
String body ;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            body = editText.getText().toString();

            Document document = new Document();
            try {
                PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(FILE));
                document.open();
                document.addSubject(body);
                document.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: FILE = "C:/FirstPdf.pdf"; ??? there is no C: try using getexternelstoragedirectory

Comment: I Was facing the same problem again even after changing the code in the way you Described

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
EditText editText;
Button button;
private static String FILE = "";
 String body ;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
FILE=(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath());
editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        body = editText.getText().toString();

        Document document = new Document();
        try {
             File temp = new File(FILE.getAbsolutePath(),"abcd.pdf");   
            PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(temp));
            document.open();
            document.addSubject(body);
            document.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }
});

}
```

there is no C: in android use Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() to get external storage path

in manifest add permission to write external storage

Comment: I mean As there is no device available right now i tried to save that in local disk.To Check whether my code was working or not

Comment: sorry your emmulator is a total device it doesnt have any connection with your s/m local storage dear and you can still try it like this and will be stored inside emulator

Comment: I Was facing the same problem again even after changing the code in the way you Described

Comment: FILE=(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"abcd.pdf");
        editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

Comment: 02-27 15:42:37.379: W/System.err(575): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mnt/sdcardabcd.pdf: open failed: EROFS (Read-only file system)

Comment: new FileOutputStream(new File(FILE)); try this

Comment: and please make sure you add the permission to write external storage directory in manifest

Comment: 02-27 15:55:05.841: W/System.err(631): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mnt/sdcardabcd.pdf: open failed: EROFS (Read-only file system)

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: have you used the latest code as your error shows /mnt/sdcardabcd.pdf: where as it should be /mnt/sdcard/abcd.pdf
  File temp = new File(FILE.getAbsolutePath(),"abcd.pdf");   
            PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(temp));

Comment: 02-27 16:04:55.559: W/System.err(677): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mnt/sdcard/abcd.pdf: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

Comment: if (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))
            cacheDir=new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"a");
        else
            cacheDir=context.getCacheDir();
        
        if(!cacheDir.exists())
            cacheDir.mkdirs();

and pass this dir instead of file .. this is the worst case but probably as you are using an emulator the error u are getting is a permission denied

Comment: no i hope not i am able to create files without any problem in emulator i hope you are messing up something else

Comment: But everything is clear i had a editText and button in my main.xml and had iText in libs and configured that and made modifications as you said...

Comment: for the last try splitting
FileOutputStream aaa=new FileOutputStream(temp);
 PdfWriter.getInstance(document, aaa);
and run in debugging mode and check what each returns

Comment: No use I Think I have to test this in Device

Comment: i tested tis code in an emulator and the file was created succesfully except for the itext jars some class missing (hope i am note using the right jar) i dont know about the particular jar in detail but abcd.pdf was created successfully even though it had no contents the warning was abcd.pdf contains no pages